# Fork with user privileges/rights

Tags: linux, sudo

Is it possible to fork a process and to run a program as normal user, e.g. with sudo rights? Or, if with sudo, with normal rights?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your process runs as root, after a fork() you can execute setgid() and setuid(), and run as a normal user in the child process, without affecting the parent process, that continues to run as root.

Comment: 'Run as root' includes started with sudo?

Comment: Well, isn't that what sudo does? Try an experiment by yourself, run your own code with sudo, and print out the values of geteuid(), getegid(), getuid(), and getgid(), and see what happens. Take advantage of this as a learning opportunity to read their manual pages, and understand the differences between them, and what they mean.